# Variable scope seems to shift with jQuery async AJAX requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, scope

I've got a item stock tracking system that I'm working on and I seem to be running into an issue with statuses being updated correctly.

Here's the JS, and from what I can tell the values of the object in the `$.each` loop that exist by the time the ajax function `success/error/complete`s is what is being used for things like where I'm injecting HTML.

```
(function() {
  function realtime() {
    // Realtime Elements...
    $('.realtime').each(function() {
      // Self Reference
      var objThis = $(this);
      // Realtime Items...
      if(objThis.hasClass('foxyinv-item')) {
        // Item Code to Check
        var valCode = objThis.find('[name=code]').val();
        // Status Element
        var objStock = objThis.find('div.stock');
        // Begin AJAX Overlap Prevention
        objThis.removeClass('realtime');
        $.ajax({
          url: 'checkstock.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            session: FC.session_id,
            code: valCode,
            qty: 1
          },
          success: function(data) {
            var response = data.split(':');
            switch(response[0]) {
              case 'ok':
                console.log(valCode+' can be sold, it is '+response[1]);
                objStock.html(valCode+'<button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>'+response[1]);
                break;
              case 'no':
                console.log(valCode+' cannot be sold, it is '+response[1]);
                objStock.html(response[1]);
                break;
              default:
                objStock.html('<span class="error">Error!</span>');
                break;
            }
          },
          error: function() {
            console.log('checkstock.php error!');
            objStock.html('<span class="error">Error!</span>');
          },
          complete: function() {
            // End AJAX Overlap Prevention
            objThis.addClass('realtime');
          }
        }); // $.ajax()
      }
    }); // $('.realtime').each()
  } // realtime()

  // Document Ready...
  $(document).on('ready', function() {
    // Main Loop...
    var RTI = setInterval(function() { realtime() }, 5000);
    realtime();
  });
})();
```

Here's the code fragment on the page which displays products

```
// Items
$items = '';
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM foxyinv_items");
if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $items .=
      '<div class="foxyinv-item realtime">'.
        '<form action="https://mlkart.foxycart.com/cart" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">'.
          '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$assoc['item_name'].'" />'.
          '<input type="hidden" name="code" value="'.$assoc['item_code'].'" />'.
          '<input type="hidden" name="price" value="'.$assoc['item_price'].'" />'.
          '<div class="name">'.$assoc['item_name'].'</div>'.
          '<div class="code">'.$assoc['item_code'].'</div>'.
          '<div class="price">'.$assoc['item_price'].'</div>'.
          '<div class="stock">Checking...</stock>'.
        '</form>'.
      '</div>';
  }
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

The callback script is working perfectly, though for example it will return these kinds of responses:

`ok:` (okay to add, no status)

`ok:In Stock` (okay to add, with status)

`no:Out of Stock` (not okay to add, with status)

`error` (error exists in mgmt panel)

The question in it's simplest would be, how do I make sure that the javascript variables `objThis`, `valCode` and `objStock` remain the same as when the ajax call is made? I'll looked into the possibility of making the ajax calls synchronously, but I do not like the implications that it will hang the page until the call completes, so synchronous calls are not an acceptable solution.

**Edit:**

Working with jfriend and commenting everything as suggested, the console indicates scope is being maintained, however when `.html(code)` is referenced, its being sent to the wrong object. Here's the console log:

```
1: start
1: inside hasClass'foxyinv-item'
1: about to call ajax, valCode=EX-02
1: objThis.data(code)=EX-02
1: success: valCode=EX-02
1: success: data=ok:In Stock
1: EX-02 can be sold, it is In Stock
1: objThis.data(code)=EX-02
1: ajax complete
1: objThis.data(code)=EX-02 
2: start
2: inside hasClass'foxyinv-item'
2: about to call ajax, valCode=EX-01
2: objThis.data(code)=EX-01
2: success: valCode=EX-01
2: success: data=error
2: EX-01 cannot be sold, it has an error!
2: objThis.data(code)=EX-01
2: ajax complete
2: objThis.data(code)=EX-01
```

This is getting weirder and weirder...

---

**Solution:**
Okay, so I feel like a complete idiot, and I'm surprised no one else picked up on it... In my item display script I so cleverly used `'<div class="stock">Checking...</stock>'`. I fixed it so that it's actually `</div>`.

Sorry to have wasted so much of your time jfriend. You did however start me down the right road since I discovered that scope was being maintained, that it had to be in another involved file. I wish I would have picked up on it sooner! The late nights and early mornings are catching up!

Comment: What you think is the problem does not appear to me to actually be an issue as all the variables you want preserved are already in a closure and thus will be preserved uniquely and available separately for each ajax call.  Can you describe more about what problem you're actually having (not what you think is causing it)?  What you think the problem is doesn't seem to be a problem.

Comment: That's what I thought, I will have to screen cap this because it is quite odd. I was figuring that the scope would be maintained, however it is not. So is the anonymous closure function that I have not adequate for this?

Comment: The `.each()` loop is adequate to create a closure and maintain those three variables you asked about.  That is not your issue.  Your issue must be something else.  We can't help further you without a more detailed description of what your problem actually is.

Comment: It would help if you told us exactly what variable doesn't have the right value inside the ajax success handler and what its value has been changed to?

Comment: I wish I could actually say what was the issue, all I know is that it's using values from prior calls later in the chain, here's a clip I took that shows how it behaves.

http://youtu.be/0oVdggEdJP4

Comment: My only other though was that because `$.ajax` is a global function its somehow shifting my local variables into the global scope and overwriting them.

Comment: Calling global functions doesn't change anything so that's not the issue.  People use `$.ajax()` just how you're using it with closures like that all the time so there's nothing wrong there.  Can you explain more about what "using values from prior calls in the chain" means?  Also, can you be more specific about what exact variable you think has the wrong value?  Your video confirms you have a problem, but doesn't shed any light on how to track it down in your code.

Comment: In cases of multiple async calls like this in flight at the same time, I often find you need to do some serious `console.log()` logging where each log call has an identifying prefix that tells you which ajax call it's part of.  Then you study the logs.  You often can't use the debugger to step through things because using the debugger changes the timing of things.

Comment: I added `console.log(valCode+' cannot be sold, it has an error!');` to the default block in the `switch` statement and when the `success/error/complete` functions fire they do so out of order as to be expected with async ajax. The problem being is that this seems confuse those 3 variables into thinking they belong to the current scope, when in reality they belong to a prior `each` scope.

Comment: I will have to tear this thing apart with `console.log` then. If I find anything I'll report back.

Comment: Sorry, but closure scopes don't get confused.  The whole web would be broken if that was the case.  Are you 100% sure you don't have a problem on the back-end with multiple requests in process at the same time and thus a wrong result getting returned?

Comment: I'm not even sure how I would check that.

Comment: For your `console.log()` debugging, what I'd suggest is that you create a global variable, let's call it `transactionId`.  Initialize it to zero in the global scope.  Then right before this `var objThis = $(this);`, do `++transactionId`.  Then, put the transaction id at the start of every `console.log()`.  That way you can see which `console.log()` statements are part of the same closure.  Then, run though a case that causes you problems and then study the logs, collecting all the log statements together with copy/paste that have the same transction id (while preserving order of them).

Comment: Got it. I'll do that and see what happens.

Comment: Let's start over here as I gave you a bit of bum advice in the previous comment.  For your `console.log()` debugging, what I'd suggest is that you create a global variable, let's call it `transactionId`. Initialize it to zero in the global scope. Then right before this `var objThis = $(this);`, do `var localTransactionId = ++transactionId;`. Then, put the `localTransactionId` at the start of every `console.log()` so you can correlate every `console.log()` with a particular closure and know which ones belong together.

Answer (score 0):

The values of any variable inside your `.each()` callback like `objThis`, `valCode` and `objStock` are in a closure and will retain their values for each separate ajax callback functions.  This is one of the advantages of using `.each()` with a callback function vs. using a `for` loop which doesn't have it's own closure built in.

Now, if the underlying data that those variables points to is modified at anytime before the ajax call completes, then you would still have a problem and the only way to fix that problem would be to either stop modifying the data you don't want to change or make a local copy of that data so nobody will mess with your copy (this doesn't look like an issue in this case).

---

To track down what exactly is happening, I suggest the following:

In the global scope declare:

```
var transactionId = 0;
```

Then, instrument your code with `console.log()` statements like this:

```
(function() {
  function realtime() {
    // Realtime Elements...
    $('.realtime').each(function() {
      var localId = ++transactionId;
      console.log(localId + ": start");
      // Self Reference
      var objThis = $(this);
      // Realtime Items...
      if(objThis.hasClass('foxyinv-item')) {
        console.log(localId + ": inside hasClass'foxyinv-item'");
        // Item Code to Check
        var valCode = objThis.find('[name=code]').val();
        // Status Element
        var objStock = objThis.find('div.stock');
        // Begin AJAX Overlap Prevention
        objThis.removeClass('realtime');
        console.log(localId + ": about to call Ajax, valCode=" + valCode);
        $.ajax({
          url: 'checkstock.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            session: FC.session_id,
            code: valCode,
            qty: 1
          },
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(localId + ": success: valCode=" + valCode);
            console.log(localId + ": success: data=" + data);
            var response = data.split(':');
            console.log(localId + ": success: response=" + response);
            switch(response[0]) {
              case 'ok':
                console.log(valCode+' can be sold, it is '+response[1]);
                objStock.html(valCode+'<button type="submit">Add to Cart</button>'+response[1]);
                break;
              case 'no':
                console.log(valCode+' cannot be sold, it is '+response[1]);
                objStock.html(response[1]);
                break;
              default:
                objStock.html('<span class="error">Error!</span>');
                break;
            }
          },
          error: function() {
            console.log(localId + ": ajax error");
            console.log('checkstock.php error!');
            objStock.html('<span class="error">Error!</span>');
          },
          complete: function() {
            console.log(localId + ": ajax complete");
            // End AJAX Overlap Prevention
            objThis.addClass('realtime');
          }
        }); // $.ajax()
      }
    }); // $('.realtime').each()
  } // realtime()

  // Document Ready...
  $(document).on('ready', function() {
    // Main Loop...
    var RTI = setInterval(function() { realtime() }, 5000);
    realtime();
  });
})();
```

---

Note: As you already surmise, you should NOT switch to synchronous ajax.  That is not the proper way to code or to solve any problem you might be having.

Comment: Added suggested `console.log()` debugging to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help here. Here's a snippet of the console output, the incorrect html slid in on the first transaction, yet all the variables indicate that scope is being maintained...

Check question for console output.

Comment: @Pentagear - did you implement my corrected second suggestion for the loggin, not the flawed first suggestion?

Comment: You're gonna laugh. I just posted the solution.

Comment: @Pentagear - oh well, figured it has to be something other than the scope issue.  Glad you got it figured.